# Performance between nested if statements vs multiple flat if not statements

Tags: python-3.x, performance

Consider the following simplified pattern:

```
def nested_ifs():
    if some_condition is True:
        # possibly do something
        if another_condition is True:
            if another is True:
                return do_this()
    # or do something else
    return None
```

And a refactored version of that:

```
def flat_ifs():
    if some_condition is not True:
        # or do something else
        return None
    # possibly do something
    if another_condition is not True:
        return None
    if another is not True:
        return None
    return do_this()
```

Personally I prefer the `flat_ifs()` way of doing things from a readability point of view, but is there a performance difference?

Comment: Can't see why there should be any difference in performance but for sure flat if statements are much more readable than nested.

Comment: I think the "canonical" way would be `if some_condition and another_condition and another: ...`.

Comment: As @Patrick Haugh mentioned, you can turn a `nested if` into a `flat if` with logical operators like `and` `or` `nand` `nor`. There won't be noticeable performance difference unless you run it on a super low performance system with old compiler/interpreter. Because now a day most of the compiler/interpreter have advance optimization on your code.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I've edited the code with some comments to create a more general case where your suggestion doesn't quite work.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, it seems like the nested loop is actually slightly faster:

```
import datetime

def nested_ifs(x):
    if True:
        if True:
            if True:
                return 10*x
    return None

def flat_ifs(x):
    if not True:
        return None
    if not True:
        return None
    if not True:
        return None
    return 10*x


nr = 100000000

begin = datetime.datetime.now()
for i in range(nr):
    nested_ifs(i)

print("nested", datetime.datetime.now() - begin)

begin2 = datetime.datetime.now()
for i in range(nr):
    flat_ifs(i)

print("flat", datetime.datetime.now() - begin2)
```

gives us:

```
nested 0:00:14.960115
flat 0:00:16.157715
```

This holds true even if one of the conditions fails.

I'd really appreciate if someone could comment why the nested way is slightly faster

Comment: You're a victim of your own cleverness here: the peephole optimizer is optimizing those `if True:` statements away, so they're never actually executed.  Using [`dis.dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#dis.dis), I count 16 instructions for your `flat_if` function and only 4 for `nested_ifs`. (I'm actually a little surprised it isn't also catching `if not True`)

Comment: Probably because you are negating the boolean in the `flat_ifs` function. Consider the number of times you ran both those functions, and how small the difference is. The difference works out to less than 0.00000002 seconds per function call. That's well within the margin of error. Basically there is no difference. That could be because of anything else that your machine was doing during the run time of the program.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Ok, that makes sense.  Would you be willing to post a more robust answer?  Else I'll play with this at some stage later and update this one